# If $n = 18k+5$ is composite, there are at least 9 divisors of $\phi(n)$ which do not divide $n-1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples

If $n$ is a composite of the form $18k+5$, there at least 9 divisors of $\phi(n)$ which do not divide $n-1$. Is this true in general or if not, what is the smallest counter example? The conjecture has been verified for $n \le 1 \times 10^7$.

[Related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245370/there-at-least-4-divisors-of-n-1-which-do-not-divide-phin-if-n-is-a-com).

**Note**: The question was [posted in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315007/if-n-18k5-is-composite-there-are-at-least-9-divisors-of-phin-which-do) a year ago but got no answer. Hence posting in MO

Comment: @GeoffRobinson "If two of the $p_i$ divide $n$ to the third power or higher, you are done" - why? I count only 8 divisors of $\varphi(n)$ not dividing $n-1$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: You are right, I was careless. I have rewritten the comment.

Comment: Any divisor of both $n-1$ and $\phi(n)$ is a divisor of $\prod_{i=1}^{k}(p_{i}-1)$, where $p_{1},p_{2}, \ldots ,p_{k}$ are the distinct primes which divide $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Positive answer to this question would imply that there are no solutions to [Lehmer's totient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem) of the form $18k+5$. I'm not aware of known restrictions of this kind.